# Find the position of a pattern/marker inside a photograph

Tags: image-processing, augmented-reality, marker

i need to find a marker like the ones used in Augmented Reality.
Like this:
[image]
I have a solid background on algebra and calculus, but no experience whatsoever on image processing. My thing is Php, sql and stuff.

I just want this to work, i've read the theory behind this and it's extremely hard to see in code for me.

The main idea is to do this as a batch process, so no interactivity is needed. What do you suggest?
Input : The sample image.
[image]

Output: Coordinates and normal vector in 3D of the marker.

The use for this will be linking images that have the same marker to spatialize them, a primitive version of photosync we could say. Just a caroussel of pinned images, the marker acting like the pin.

The reps given allowed me to post images, thanks.

Comment: You can add images now. They will make the question more answerable, I hope.

Comment: Thanks @Lazer this is much more aswerable now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always look at the open source libraries such as [ARToolkit](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/) and see how it works but generally in order to get the 3D coordinates of marker you would need to:

1. Do the [camera calibration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning).
2. Find marker in image using [local features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_%28computer_vision%29) for example.
3. Using calibrated camera parameters and 2D coordinates of marker do the approximation the 3D coordinates.

I've never implemented sth similar by myself but I think this is a general concept you should apply on your method.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by perspective n point camera pose estimation. When you can reasonably assume that all correspondences are correct, a [linear](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.44.7155) algorithm should do.

Since the marker is planar, you can also recover the displacement from the homography between the model plane and the image plane ([link](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/zhang/calib/)). As usual, best results are obtained by iterative algorithms ([link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.89.6052)).

Comment: Can you tell me what "perspective n point camera pose estimation" is?

Comment: The algorithm estimates the camera pose from projections of n known 3D points (have you checked the first link in the answer above?). In your case you could use the six corners of the inner white polygon. For simplicity you might choose the 3D world coordinate system so that the 3D points are (0,0,0), (2,0,0), (0,2,0), (1,2,0), (2,1,0), (1,1,0). Then you measure their position in the normalized image coordinates (you need to have a calibrated camera). Finally you invoke the linear PnP algorithm and obtain the camera pose.